# Flash message Rails 4- Not displaying properly - Index and Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, ruby-on-rails-4

I have added the following to my HomeController (/app/controllers/home_controller.rb) :

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    flash[:notice] = "wowza"
  end

end
```

I then added the following to my application.html.erb file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>FlashTest</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting that a flash message saying "wowza" would be displayed, but instead it just says "wowza" in text on the page. How can I make the page display the flash message?

Comment: You mean you need to display the text '"wowza" would be displayed' as notice message?

Comment: What do you mean by a "flash message"?

Comment: Thanks - I realize now that it was working, but just didn't have any cool effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has confused me, presumably because we have different interpretations of what `flash message` means --

> From the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash):
>
> The flash is a special part of the session which is cleared with each
>   request. This means that values stored there will only be available in
>   the next request, which is useful for passing error messages etc.

I believe your problem is less a `flash` issue, and more a `styling` issue. To Rails, the `Flash` is basically a type of session cookie which perishes after each request. It's loaded each time you load a page, and allows you to output simple action-centric messages. It has nothing to do with styling

If you detail how you'd like your flash messages to appear, it will be a big help; but in the meantime, here's what we do:

---

**FadeOut**

We have this code to fade out flash:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee
flashCallback = ->
    $(".notice").animate
      height: 0
      opacity: 0
    , 350
    , ->
      $(this).remove()

$ ->
    $(".notice").bind 'click', (ev) =>
        flashCallback()
    setTimeout flashCallback, 3000
```

This allows your flash to `fade out` when displayed on the page. Probably what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks - I realize now that it was working, but just didn't have any cool effects.